# How Mongoose Paginate works with MongoDB and Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

**I am trying to implement Mongoose paginate** in the project, I have 2 controllers, `Controller-main.js` from where I am sending requests and receive responses, and `controller-search.js` where I am running MongoDB queries based on requests and sending ids as responses.

`Controller-main.js` from where I am sending req/res -

```
    var articlepost = (req, res) => {
    let page = req.body.page ? req.body.page : 1;
  
    let perpage = req.body.perpage ? req.body.perpage : 100;
  
 
  
    if (req.body.sortdate == "asc") {
      datesort = -1;
      var options = {
        page: parseInt(page, 10) || 1,
        limit: parseInt(perpage, 10) || 100,
        sort: {
          pubdate: datesort,
        },
      };
    } else if (req.body.sortdate == "desc") {
      datesort = 1;
      var options = {
        page: parseInt(page, 10) || 1,
        limit: parseInt(perpage, 10) || 100,
        sort: {
          pubdate: datesort,
        },
      };
    } else if (req.body.sortdate == "current") {
      datesort = -1;
      var options = {
        page: parseInt(page, 10) || 1,
        limit: parseInt(perpage, 10) || 100,
        sort: {
          captureddatetime: datesort,
        },
      };
    }
  
    var query = {};

    let fromdate = req.body.fromdate;
    let todate = req.body.todate;
  
    query.pubdate = {
      $gte: todate,
      $lte: fromdate,
    };
  
  

  
    query.rejected = 0;
    
    //fulltext code intiates here
    if (req.body.fullTextKeyword != "") {
      //FullText Search
      let _fullText = req.body.fullTextKeyword;
      request.post(
        {
          url: "http://localhost:3000/search/getarticles",
          method: "POST",
          body: { groupkeyword: _fullText, fdate: todate, tdate: fromdate },
          json: true,
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
          query.articleid = {
            $in: body, //where in condition
          };
          articlesModule.paginate(query, options, function (err, impacts) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("error 2" + err);
              res.status(500);
              res.send("internal error");
            } else {
              res.status(200);
              console.log("sending data");
              res.json(impacts);
            }
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      articlesModule.paginate(query, options, function (err, impacts) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error 2" + err);
          res.status(500);
          res.send("internal error");
        } else {
          res.status(200);
           
          console.log("sending data");
          res.json(impacts);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

**`controller-search.js`** page where queries run -

```
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page || fulltextOptions.page);
const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit || fulltextOptions.limit);
  // Validate page and limit parameters
  if (isNaN(page) || page < 1) {
    page = 1;
  }
  if (isNaN(limit) || limit < 1 || limit > 100) {
    limit = 10;
  }

  let agg;
  let mustArray = [];
  let shouldArray = [];

  if (keywords.length === 1) {
    agg = [
      {
        $search: {
          index: "fulltext",
          text: {
            query: keywords[0],
            path: ["headline", "fulltext", "subtitle"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          articleid: 1,
          _id: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        $skip: (page - 1) * limit, // calculate the number of documents to skip
      },
      {
        $limit: limit, // limit the number of documents to return per page
      },
    ];
  

  searchModel.aggregate(agg, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500);
    } else {
      const _articleids = data.map((x) => x.articleid);

      res.status(200).json(_articleids);
    }
  });
};
module.exports = {
  getArticles,
};
```

Now when I check the query, **I found skip and limits are attached to it** -

```
[{"$search":{"index":"fulltext","text":{"query":"STACK","path":["headline","fulltext","subtitle"]}}},{"$project":{"articleid":1,"_id":0}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":100}]
```

**but it is not utilizing pagination, as I have checked without the limit the records are 1000+ show** with page 1,2 options, but with `limit` and `skip` in the query it shows only 4 records and there is no option for pages - 1,2 or the next page, How will I implement the pagination correctly?